# Whether a form is disposed after calling form.hide()?

Tags: c#, hide, dispose, showdialog, formclosing

I'm newbie and I've searched for many answer of this problem but I don't really understand. I have 2 forms: `LoginForm` and `EditForm`. When `LoginForm` is hidden and `EditForm` is showed. `EditForm` works with 5 images (13Mb). Therefore, my question is that whether 5 images will be disposed when I call `this.Hide()`or not?

```
private void doctorLogoutBtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    this.Hide(); //Everything in EditForm is disposed?
    LoginForm Login = new LoginForm();
    Login.ShowDialog();
}
```

If not, is there anyway to dispose 5 images when closing the form?

Answer (score 1):

No. Using Hide() is the same as setting the form's Visible property to false.

To dispose, you must use the Dispose() method on the form object.